# <PostalCodeElementGetting this Error: index.js:2177 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

So this code was working earlier but I had to reinstall react-stripe-elements using npm after which I started getting the error. When I remove . The code works again. Any ideas why?

```
<div>
   <PostalCodeElement
      onBlur={this.handleBlur}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      placeholder='Zip code'
      {...createOptions()}
     />
</div>
```

Full Error:

> index.js:2177 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.

Answer (score 0):

`PostalCodeElement` was removed in react-stripe-elements v3: https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/blob/918a900aadaa4ab97b2d3d58c5889ab3a016a164/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes

You need to either build your own or use an older version of the library, bear in mind that older versions won't have support for the new PaymentIntents API.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/322 Just saw this. They are removing the Element.